# Using DECLARE to create variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

I will admit, I am a T-SQL guy, not a MySQL guy, but I don't quite understand why I am getting this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @UpdatedID VARCHAR(5)' at line 1
```

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @UpdatedID VARCHAR(5);

SET @UpdatedID = 63;

CREATE TABLE tmp_markers (SELECT * FROM tmp_markers2);

UPDATE tmp_markers
SET Id = Id+1
WHERE Id >= @UpdatedID;

UPDATE tmp_markers
SET Id = @UpdatedID
WHERE Id = MAX(Id);

DELETE from tmp_markers2;

INSERT INTO tmp_markers2
(SELECT * FROM tmp_markers ORDER BY id);

DROP TABLE tmp_markers
```

Comment: It's not possible to "declare" variable as you've specified without stored routines/functions scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a variable in MySQL is done with what you have done with:

```
SET @UpdatedID = 63;
```

The `DECLARE` statement is for use within stored procedures. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html).